# What is Neri's full name?

Tags: names, ocean-girl

In *Ocean Girl*, what is Neri's full name? In all the 4 series of *Ocean Girl*, I never heard anyone mentioning or talking about her full name. Besides Neri had a father and mother still alive, so she must have a full name.

Comment: Wasn't Neri an alien from another world though? In which case, there's no particular reason to think she has a first name and surname according to the same naming system as used on Earth (and not even in all countries on Earth).

Comment: Note that Neri's father was Dead when she was little

Comment: And not just an alien from another world, royalty too, so: Her Royal Highness, The Princess Neri should be enough...